# How to take entry from a form, combine it with other text and create a new file on the server with the content

Tags: php

I'm not looking for code, but just to help me think about the best way of achieving this.

In a nutshell I need to take user input from a form, wrap that content in my own code, and then output the result into a new .js file on the sever.

Are there any examples people can point me towards. I'm familiar with Javascript, but not php and file handling.

Comment: You are planning to create a new js file for every form submission? Without more information, I already think you are doing something wrong. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: There are several ways to write to file, for example `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()`. Make sure you have proper permission

Answer (score 0):

If you have proper rights on the server, first get the values from the posted form like this =>

```
$formInput1 = $_POST["formInput1"];
```

If the form action attribute is set to "post", otherwise :

```
$formInput1 = $_GET["formInput1"];

// Do what you have to do with all your inputs
// ....
```

After that, you have to create a new file :

```
$myJSFile = fopen("some_name.js", "r+"); // See the PHP doc for modifiers
fwrite($myJSFile, $formInput1);
fclose($myJSFile);
```

But... Keep in mind that by this way you risk to have thousands js files on your server, that you have to find a single name for each new file and... last thing, i don't know how you will manage those files after that, i mean, how will you load the correct JS file in the next navigation ?